# Метод audio.get — Доступ закрыт, нет доступа до данного метода (VK API)

Tags: c#, .net, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

```
WebRequest request =
    WebRequest.Create("https://api.vk.com/method/audio.get?owner_id=" + Settings1.Default.id + "&need_user=0&access_token=" + Settings1.Default.token);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
response.Close();
responseFromServer = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(responseFromServer);

JToken token = JToken.Parse(responseFromServer);
audioList = token["response"].Children().Skip(1).Select(c => c.ToObject<Audio>()).ToList();
```

Приходит `response`:

> доступ закрыт, нет доступа до данного метода.

Comment: а вы права получали? см. https://vk.com/dev/audio.get: *Для вызова этого метода Ваше приложение должно иметь права: audio*

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Строку получения токена в студию. Скорее всего ответ в ней и лежит.

Comment: получил уже наконец

Comment: теперь другая проблема JToken token = JToken.Parse(responseFromServer);
            audioList = Enumerable.Skip(token["response"].Children(), 1).Select(c => c.ToObject<Audio>()).ToList();   выдает ошибку An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unexpected token while deserializing object: PropertyName. Path '', line 1, position 33.

Comment: да , права получил , и уже все работает

Comment: теперь другая проблема JToken token = JToken.Parse(responseFromServer); audioList = Enumerable.Skip(token["response"].Children(), 1).Select(c => c.ToObject<Audio>()).ToList(); выдает ошибку An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Unexpected token while deserializing object: PropertyName. Path '', line 1, position 33.